# scraping and storing scraped information to a csv file

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

How can I get the scraped information to be put into a csv file and then close the tab and write it into a new one and loop it through until all of the pages in the forum has been scraped I'm still learning more about web scraping and I'm completely stuck on this the div name that needs to be scraped is "post-content" but it doesn't show the correct information when I'm testing it

```
import driver as driver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common import window
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import csv

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://navalcommand.enjin.com/forum/viewforum/2989694/m/11178354/page/1")
elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='structure small-cells']//a[@href]")
links = []

# create csv file
f = open(r"C:\Users\jammi\OneDrive\Desktop\Navcom\test.csv", 'w', encoding='UTF8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(f)

# to open every thread link
for ele in elems:
    if "viewthread" in ele.get_attribute("href"):
        links.append(ele.get_attribute("href"))
        links = list(dict.fromkeys(links))
        print(elems)
# to open every link into a new tab
for link in links:
    driver.switch_to.new_window(window.WindowTypes.TAB)
    driver.get(link)

# write the scraped information to a csv file
content = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "post-content")
print(content)
csvWriter.writerow([content])
```

Comment: Do you need all posts or just the first one?  Do you only need the text of the post or do you also need the name of its author?

Comment: all of the posts and then going to the next page

Comment: Do you want to write all the data to one csv file or is each thread a new csv file?

Comment: If its possible new file for a new thread

Comment: but theres also some images is there a way to save them with the create file loop or will I have to make a different loop for that?

Comment: You can do check inside the loop where we get the posts. If we get an empty string, then we look for link to the image and add it to csv. Updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```py
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
                                    

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# disable chromedriver log message in cmd
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])

service = Service(executable_path="path/to/your/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://navalcommand.enjin.com/forum/viewforum/2989694/m/11178354/page/1")
# get number of pages
num_pages = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.text.rightmost").text.split(' ')[1]

for page in range(2, int(num_pages)):
    # find all threads on the current page
    threads = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.thread-view.thread-subject")))
    # get links to threads
    thread_links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in threads]
    # open each link and get all the posts in thread
    for link in thread_links:
        driver.get(link)
        thread_content = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.post-content")
        # get thread id
        thread_id = driver.current_url.split('d/')[1].split('-')[0]
        # save received data in csv
        for post in thread_content:
            post_content = post.text or post.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'img').get_attribute('src')
            with open(file=f'{thread_id}_navalcommand.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
                writer.writerow([post_content])
    driver.get(f"https://navalcommand.enjin.com/forum/viewforum/2989694/m/11178354/page/{page}")

driver.quit()
```

Output is list of csv files:

```
32694465_navalcommand.csv
33053469_navalcommand.csv
33079839_navalcommand.csv
```

Each file is a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `xpath` again for the `post-content` search.

```
content = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='post-content']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is blocked while accessing it through Selenium. So, I have used another URL and modified your code, just take the logic from the below code and also modify the locators as per your need:

This code will get all the URLs from the main page, iterate through and open each link in a new tab, print the content and save the content to '.csv' file, close the tab then move to the next link.

```
driver.get("https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=326")           # Change this URL to your URL

elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='threadtitle']//a[@href]")           # Change this XPath as per your website
print("Length: ", len(elems))
links = []

# create csv file
f = open(r"C:\Users\<user name>\Downloads\test.csv", 'w', encoding='UTF8')                  # modify this path
csvWriter = csv.writer(f)

# to open every thread link
for i in range(len(elems)):
    if "showthread" in elems[i].get_attribute("href"):              # Change 'showthread' to the original - 'viewthread'
        links.append(elems[i].get_attribute("href"))
        links = list(dict.fromkeys(links))                      # I am not sure why you are using this line here, anyway that's your decision
        # print("Elements: ", elems)

print("Links: ", links)
print("")

# to open every link into a new tab
for link in links:
    driver.switch_to.new_window(window.WindowTypes.TAB)
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Contents of '", driver.title, "' page")
    print("----")
    # write the scraped information to a csv file
    no_of_content = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".postcontent.restore")               # Change '.postcontent.restore' to the original - '.post-content', but use CSS_SELECTOR
    for i in range(len(no_of_content)):
        print("Content: ", no_of_content[i].text)
        csvWriter.writerow([no_of_content[i].text])
        time.sleep(1)
    print("=============End of the page=================")
    print("")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```